# Components Library in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

Is possible to use two library components in the same App? For example use Mudblazor and Telerik. The particular case is that I need to use a table from Telerik but just that. So maabe there is a way to use a specific component library in one specific component or somthig like that.

Comment: You might also look at using HAVIT Blazor which is based on Bootstrap 5 and it's free.  They have some very nicely made controls, including a GridView table.  And if it works for  you then you would not need to mix and match multiple control libraries.  See: https://havit.blazor.eu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is no problem with that - I did it for MudBlazor and Syncfusion - as long as you are sure, that installers for them are not overwriting each other. Check mostly for JavaScript scripts for things like dialogs / popups / toasts and `CSS` - both of those libraries may style the same `html` tags. As for using only specific component - it depends on the provider - Syncfusion provides separate components for each control.
You could always modify package from Telerik, remove unused css styling, java etc, but this will break compatibility when updates will be installed and some changes have been made on provider's side.